# Failed to find package.json. Node.js may have issues starting. error when deploying to ElasticBeanstalk using Code Pipeline

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I am trying to commit code to Elastic Beanstalk  using CodeCommit and CodePipeline and get the following error "Failed to find package.json. Node.js may have issues starting. Verify package.json is valid or place code in a file named server.js or app.js."

I saw this error could be caused by zipping up a folder with the required contents instead of just zipping up required contents. When I upload the zip file directly to Elastic Beanstalk, there are no deployment issues.

Comment: You need to provide details of your pipeline. Specicaly how did you set up input and outputs for each action? Do you have a build stage?

Comment: I didn't have a build stage, since the tutorial on AWS docs I was following said not to